# How to exclude multiple columns in gather function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data composed of columns with following names  : `ID,A,B,C,A_5,B_5,C_5`

I want to use `gather()` function such that `ID,A_5,B_5` and `C_5` are excluded. I know that if I wanted to exclude only `ID`, I could have written :

```
df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -ID)
```

But I could not figure out the way to exclude multiple columns at once. I would appreciate a lot if somebody can tell me the correct syntax. So far I have tried and failed with:

```
df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -vars(ID,A_5,B_5,C_5)
df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -c(ID,A_5,B_5,C_5)
df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -list(ID,A_5,B_5,C_5)
df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -list(ID,A_5,B_5,C_5)
```

Also I have several other data frames on which I would like to perform the same operation. They all have different column lengths and for some, I need to exclude more than 10 columns. Thus, referring to these columns by their index would be much more convenient. Is this possible? If so, how can it be achieved?

I did not provide a reproducible example since this is merely a question of syntax. I hope it is ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -ID, -A_5, -B_5, -C_5)` ? Or `df %>% gather(key = categories ,value = value, -c(ID, A_5, B_5, C_5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt works for me:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3), Col2 = c(7, 9, 8, 1), ID = "ID", A_5 = "Test1", B_5 = "Test2", C_5 = "Test3")
df %>% gather(key = categories, value = value, -c(ID, A_5, B_5, C_5))
```

Output:

```
  ID   A_5   B_5   C_5 categories value
1 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col1     1
2 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col1     2
3 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col1     2
4 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col1     3
5 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col2     7
6 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col2     9
7 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col2     8
8 ID Test1 Test2 Test3       Col2     1
```

If this doesn't work for you for some reason, try updating your packages, or quoting the column names: -c("ID", "A_5", "B_5", "C_5")

Or, to exclude using the index of the columns (same output):

```
toExclude <- names(df)[3:6]
df %>% gather(key = categories, value = value, -toExclude)
```

Comment: You're right. I was getting an error due to some other syntax error apparently, the second option indeed works. But the alternative with the indices is even better, thanks a lot.